# Using jquery variable as CSS property

Tags: jquery, css

forgive me if I'm not asking this properly, I'm new to this site.  I'm working on the Etch-a-Sketch project from The Odin Project, some of you may be familiar with it.  Basically at this point, what I'm trying to do is resize some divs using a button in jquery, and I wanted to know if it's possible to set a CSS property of those divs (height and width) with a function where I'm using a jquery variable to set the new size.

When I click the New Grid button, I want it to resize the height and width of my divs based on the number I enter in the prompt.

Here's what I have so far:

```
$("#new_grid").click(function() {

var height = 448 / size;
var width = 448 / size;
var resizePix = function() {
    $(".pixel").css({"height": ???, "width": ???});
        $(".pixel").appendTo("#grid");
    }

var size = prompt("Enter new grid size (10 - 100):");
    if (size < 10) {
        alert("Number is too small.");
    } else if (size > 100) {
        alert("Number is too big.");
    } else if (size >= 10 || size <= 100) {
        resizePix();
        }
```

What I'm looking to do is have the CSS properties of .pixel reflect the "size" variable that comes from whatever number is entered in the prompt after clicking the button. For example, if I enter 20 when prompted, that should result in dividing 448 (height and width of my container div which holds the divs I'm trying to resize) by 20, and using that value to change the CSS height and width properties.

Am I going about this the right way?  I know the resizePix function works because if I just use regular values to change the CSS, the changes are reflected when using the button. I just can't figure out how to get my height and width variables to change the CSS properties.

Comment: not sure if I understand, but is this what you're trying to do? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EmyqvQ

Comment: Why you use `$(".pixel").appendTo("#grid");` doesn't the number of cells depends on the new grid size?

Comment: Also this `else if (size >= 10 || size <= 100) {` is totally unnecessary. You need only `else {` (since you already defined the range in the previous statements)

Comment: @MichaelCoker Yes, that is the basic idea, but that code will not resize my divs.  I have tried a few variations of the CSS portion you used, but none seem to work.

Comment: @JustinD what CSS exactly he used? I see not a single line of CSS

Comment: @JustinD can you post the project? There could be any number of problems.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thanks for the input,  not sure what you mean with your question though. The grid itself, at least the way I did it, is always 448px by 448px, I'm just trying to resize the divs (pixels) that will then show up in that grid.  So say I enter "20" when prompted, the grid should fit 20 "pixels" across and 20 "pixels" up and down.

Comment: @MichaelCoker Sure, the project is explained here:
http://www.theodinproject.com/courses/web-development-101/lessons/javascript-and-jquery

Comment: @JustinD noooo.... I mean post all of your code so we can see `.pixel` not updating. I'm not going to take the tutorial, but may help you with the specific problem you're trying to solve if you give enough context so that I don't have to guess at what it could be.

Comment: @JustinD ahaa so all the cells already exist! just in another "container" Element... that's totally stupid - whoever made that requirement. The proper way is to simply create new fresh elements on the fly.

Comment: @MichaelCoker Haha, sorry, didn't know what you meant. I got it figured out though, thanks!

Comment: @JustinD np. was the fix moving the division inside your function?

Comment: @MichaelCoker It was, I would have saved a lot of time if I just came here to ask sooner. Such an easy fix, but I thought the problem was with how I was trying to get the variables to work as CSS properties.

Comment: @JustinD did you see that I put that in the codepen I posted in reply to your post?

Comment: @MichaelCoker Oops, I didn't notice that, I only really looked at how you did the CSS portion, I thought the rest was just the same code I had posted here.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide inside your function, not outside of it

```js
function resizePix(size) {
  const px = 448 / size; // (P.S: Math.round() could also help?)
  $(".pixel").css({height: px, width: px});
}


$("#new_grid").on("click", function() {

  const size = prompt("Enter new grid size (10 - 100):");

  if (size < 10) {
    alert("Number is too small.");
  } else if (size > 100) {
    alert("Number is too big.");
  } else { 
    resizePix(size);
  }

});
```

```css
.pixel {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="new_grid">GRID SIZE</button>
<div id="grid">
  <div class="pixel"></div>
</div>
```